# Generate the Apk for API Level 19 in ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I want to create the android app for the min-sdk version 19. I have also configured the **config.xml** like this:

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
 <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

then installed the apk on the android 4.4.4, it works fine but the app stops while opening the google map. Anyone if know how to generate the Apk for Api level 19 please help..

Answer (score 1):

To better optimize your app for devices running Android 4.4, you should set your targetSdkVersion to "19", install it on an Android 4.4 system image, test it, then publish an update with this change.

You can use APIs in Android 4.4 while also supporting older versions by adding conditions to your code that check for the system API level before executing APIs not supported by your minSdkVersion.

For More Details, goto https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

I Hope this was helpful.

Comment: <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
 I have set the targetSdkVersion 19 but it still does not work.. any other solution????

Comment: It's seems like maybe you have not added `google_play_servies.lib` into your project. Supposedly, if you have do make sure that it's a version supported by your current targetSDKVersion. And, also this 
 dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' `should be in your build.gradle file.

Comment: There are too many build.gradle files in the project folder. Please specify where should i check this dependency.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/23241888/6805145 - Refer this link..Inshallah, you will find your answer over here regarding which `build.gradle` file you should modify ! Hopefully, :-)

Comment: The dependency compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' is present in the build.gradle file.

Comment: I tested it on mobile it works fine but it cannot open google map and the error message displays Unfortunately app has stopped. Thats it. I think there may be the problem with the plugin...

Comment: Can you show me what comes in the error log when your app crashes ? And, have you updated your Android Support SDK and Google Play service libraries inside of the SDK Manager ?

Comment: I used the native feature and it can only be run on the android phone so there is no error log generated on the mobile, but only a message is displayed.

Comment: But you can connect your device and debug it via android studio..just keep an eye for information displayed in the ADB Logcat Console, especially before when the app crashes. That way, you and i will both know what causes the app to crash.